# How do I reduce the Total Sum of a Continuous Variable by Using binary variables in a Binary Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization, integer-programming, python

Columns are in this orders: Container | Box Cylinder | Cylinder weight (g) | Cylinder volume (mL) | Density (g/mL)

Can someone help me to mathematically formulate this problem into a Linear Programing Optimization Problem?

My formulation of the problem is as follows:

$$\sum_i \sum_j \sum_k C_i B_{ji} Cy_{jk} D[Cy_{jk}] = 3.6493g/ml$$

since $$ density = m / V$$

s.t:

$$\sum_i C_i = 35$$
$$C_i \in \{0, 1\}$$
$$\sum_j B_{ji} >= 1$$
$$B_{ji} \in \max{0, C_{ij}}$$
$$\sum Cy_{jk} = 1$$
$$Cy_{jk} \in \max{0, B_{ji}}$$

Comment: What have you tried? Also, would you be able to re-edit your question and add a “!” behind the brackets of your image link to bring it to the body?

Comment: Hi @PseudoLooped, I've tried to put the "!", but since I am a new user it says I neet at leat 10 reputation points to post an image. I've been thinking about how to formulate the problem, but have not yet figured out. I'm trying to go trough this link to see if I have some ideas: https://towardsdatascience.com/hands-on-integer-binary-linear-optimization-using-python-b6d8160cb1de

Comment: This can be solved with a model, what you’ll need to do is analyze the problem for 1) something that can be a decision variable(s), 2) constraints; limiting factors that will influence the found decision variables, 3) an objective function that’s the goal of the model that will help you solve this problem

Comment: The more-than-one winner option is hinting at a multiple-optimal solution. the decision variables seem to be the containers, boxes, and cylinders

Comment: sum of C_i * B_j * Cy_jk * W[Cy_jk] = 18.844 kg and sum of C_i * B_j * Cy_jk * V[Cy_jk] = 5163.69 ml, st. sum C_i = 35, C_i in {0, 1}, B_j >= 1, B_j  in {0, max num of boxes in that container}, sum Cy_jk >= 1 and Cy_jk in {0, max num of cylinder in that box}. Should be something link that @PseudoLooped ?

Comment: something like that, it's hard to read because it's in comment form, but it looks like you're on the right path. you should edit your post with that model/attempt so we have more to work with in order to assist you

Comment: Hi @PseudoLooped I have added my current solution in a more well formated way

Answer (score 0):

Let binary decision variable $x_{ijk}$ indicate whether container $i$, box $j$, and cylinder $k$ are selected, and let binary decision variable $y_i$ indicate whether container $i$ is selected.  A straightforward linear formulation is
\begin{align}
\sum_i y_i &= 35 \label1\tag1 \\
\sum_{i,j,k} v_{ijk} x_{ijk} &\ge 5163.69 \label2\tag2\\
\sum_{i,j,k} w_{ijk} x_{ijk} &\ge 18.844 \label3\tag3\\
\sum_k x_{ijk} &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \label4\tag4\\
x_{ijk} &\le y_i &&\text{for all $i,j,k$} \label5\tag5
\end{align}
A stronger formulation replaces \eqref{4} and \eqref{5} with
\begin{align}
\sum_k x_{ijk} &\le y_i &&\text{for all $i,j$} \label6\tag6
\end{align}

Comment: (1) is the objetive function and all others are constraints? @RobPrat

Comment: No, they are all constraints.  You can use whatever (linear) objective you want.  Every feasible solution wins the game.